# Нужны ли запятые в предложении с деепричастным оборотом?

Tags: запятые, однородные-члены, деепричастный-оборот

Пишу сочинение по картине С. Григорьева «Вратарь». Помогите, пожалуйста.
Нужно ли ставить запятые в этом предложении? Если да, то где?

*Сзади вратаря стоит совершенно спокойно и не боясь ничего его друг.*

Comment: Здравствуйте, добро пожаловать на наш сайт! Запятые нигде не нужны, т. к. два обстоятельства соединены союзом И.

Answer (score 4):

*Сзади вратаря стоит **совершенно спокойно** и **не боясь ничего** его друг.*

Постановка запятых в предложении не требуется, несмотря на наличие деепричастного оборота. Он выступает как однородный член с необособленным обстоятельством *совершенно спокойно*, поэтому запятая не ставится.

> **Примечание.** Одиночное деепричастие или деепричастный оборот не обособляется: <...>
> **6)** если деепричастный оборот выступает в качестве однородного члена предложения с необособленным обстоятельством: *Алёша длинно  **и как-то прищурив глаза** посмотрел на Ракитина* (Дост.); *…Вдруг завопила она раздирающим воплем **и залившись слезами*** (Дост.); *Остановив Власову, он одним дыханием **и не ожидая ответов** закидал её трескучими и сухими словами* (М.Г.); *Клим Самгин шагал по улице бодро **и не уступая дорогу встречным людям*** (М.Г.)...

P. S. *Сзади* я бы заменил на *позади*, звучит покрасивше.

[Деепричастные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113)

Comment: Так и есть, ставлю плюс на ваш ответ.